# In PHP how do I type hint an instance of a class accessed using a string as the class name

Tags: php, laravel, type-hinting, laravel-query-builder, psalm-php

Using Laravel, I'm iterating through a series of classes and doing an operation on a subset of instances of each class. The classes are provided as strings, eg:

```php
$c = '\App\Models\Book';

$c::each(function($i) {
    echo $i->title . PHP_EOL;
});
```

How would I type hint `$i`?

Comment: Do all classes share a common interface? Or a common parent class? Without knowing more about these classes, it's pretty difficult to tell you what to add

Comment: @NicoHaase they all extend the standard `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`

Comment: But not all of them have a `title`  field? Then I don't see any possibility to add a proper type hint

Comment: if they are all models then you could type hint `Model`, but you don't need a type hint at all, especially since you are most likely accessing dynamic properties (attributes, relationships) of the model any way, which are not actually defined on any model instance any way

Comment: What is the purpose of type hinting here? What benefit will you achieve by type hinting? If it’s to allow your IDE to pickup details, there are plugins which do this for you (in phpstorm)

Comment: Thanks all. This was more of a thought excercise, based on Psalm flagging a notice/info for an equivalent situation. I know that I don't have to type hint, I was merely interested as to whether it's possible in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can type it as `object{title:string}`, if you sure about `title` and wants to tell about it to `paslm`.

Also, maybe you may find useful conditional types - https://psalm.dev/docs/annotating_code/type_syntax/conditional_types/